# While loop for re-prompt user after invalid input continues in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, contains

I want to re-prompt the user after a invalid input (empty or does not exist). The code below helps me do that **but even if a valid input is given, it will still prompt the user for another input.** How can I stop the loop from running again once a valid input is inserted?

```
    //get user input
    String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input");

    try{
        while (true) {
            List <WebElement> PageScrubberPagelet = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='_3d5d']//a[contains(@data-key,'')]"));            
            for (WebElement el:PageScrubberPagelet) {
                if (!(el.getAttribute("data-key")).contains(year) || year.equals("")) {
                    year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid input. Please re-enter (recent/ YYYY)", 
                        "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                } else {
                    //find and click on the input year
                    WebElement yearButton = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'" + year + "')]"));                        
                    yearButton.click(); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(ExpandFacebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Invalid input!", e);
    }
```

If the while loop is replace with if, it will only allow once for a invalid input and will not re-prompt the user for a third time.

Answer (score 1):

Use this template as a guide for you to solve the problem! Shouldn't be too hard, just a simple `do-while loop`. Since you want what's inside to execute at least once to get the first set of input to test, then loop from there on if necessary:

```
do
{
    <GET USER INPUT>
} while (<USER INPUT> != <CORRECT DATA>);
```

Answer (score 0):

The break only breaks the inner most loop (the for loop).  You need to then break out from the outermost loop.  A better way to do this is

```
    boolean goodInput = false;
    do {
        for (WebElement el:PageScrubberPagelet) {
            if (!(el.getAttribute("data-key")).contains(year) || year.equals("")) {
                year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid input. Please re-enter (recent/ YYYY)", 
                    "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                //find and click on the input year
                WebElement yearButton = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'" + year + "')]"));                        
                yearButton.click(); 
                goodInput = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!goodInput);
```

Comment: your answer works fine to stop the loop from continuing, but it sort of prevented the attributes for the webelements to be retrieved, as i have to key the correct input for e.g 3 times before it will click on the button even though it is a valid input.